# Find all whole numbers such that the number increased by the sum of its digits equals 73.

Tags: decimal-expansion

I'm really lost on how to figure this out. Work shown would help.

Comment: Brute force is also an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the number must have two digits, so it is 10a+b. What is an expression for the number plus the sum of its digits?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You can immediately rule out any single digit number, and all whole numbers with three or more digits. (Why?)

Consequently, you're looking at two-digit whole numbers $n$, which can all be expressed in the form $$n=d_1\cdot 10+d_2,$$ where $d_1,d_2\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and $d_1\ne0.$ (Why?)

So what you want is that $n+d_1+d_2=73.$ Can you rewrite $n+d_1+d_2$ in terms of $d_1$ and $d_2,$ and take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

It would have to be two digits, say $ab$. Then the sum is $$(10a+b)+(a+b)=11a+2b=73$$ For this to work, $a$ must be odd, and $$b=\frac{73-11a}{2}\in [1,9]\implies a=5,6$$ So the only solution is $$a=5, b=9 \\ 59$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be the number in question. Clearly, the standard decimal representation of $n$ must have two digits, so $n = 10a + b$. Then the condition becomes $73 = n + a + b$. Substituting in, we have $$11a + 2b = 73.$$ Now, we need to find $b, 0\leq b\leq 9$ such that $73-2b$ is divisible by $11$. I will leave the rest to you.

Comment: $$11a+2b=73\iff11(a-5)=2(9-b)\iff\frac{a-5}2=\frac{9-b}{11}=c$$  $$\implies 0\le a=2c+5<10\iff c=0,1,2$$ and $$0\le9-11c=b<10\implies c=0$$